# How to propely integration test ElasticSearch? My integration tests are non-deterministic

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I want to integration test a class that stores data in ElasticSearch. Typically, I want to add some data using tested class and then check if data is present on Elastic.

Example test method:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    ElasticClient.DeleteByQuery(Indices.Index(IndexName), d =>
        d.Query(x => x.MatchAll())
    );
}

[Test]
public async Task GetAllConversations_ShouldReturnAllConversations()
{
    // Arrange
    Guid[] randomGuids = new[]
    {
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        Guid.NewGuid(),
    };

    foreach (var randomGuid in randomGuids)
    {
        await _conversationStorage.AddMessage(randomGuid, new Message()
        {
            Text = "test",
            Type = MessageType.UserMade
        });
    }

    // Act
    var result = await _sut.GetAllConversations();
    
    // Assert
    Assert.That(result?.Conversations.Count, Is.EqualTo(4));
}
```

(`AddMessage` does `IndexAsync` inside)

My problem is that my method seems to be non-deterministic. It usually passes (and I can see that data appears on Elastic), but sometimes it doesn't. Running it again makes the test pass again.

Can I somehow ensure that all data that were recently added are indexed on Elastic and that I can safely perform "Assert" checks?

I'm using `Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch` .NET library and ElasticSearch version 8.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Documents indexed in elasticsearch are not available for search immediately after indexing. I am actually surprised it works at all. I think you might have some problems with cleaning up as well. For the documents to show up in the search the index should be [refreshed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html). This operation occurs automatically every second by default. But you can force it.

Forcing the refresh operation after each indexing is not recommended in production since it leads to poor performance but this is perfectly fine in your scenario.

Another note: it's typically much faster and cleaner to just delete and re-create the index than delete all records from the index.